# Efficient way to load indexed text file into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a *large* text file which has the format:

```
ID   Data
1    4,5,6,7,2,3,4
3    1,2,3,6,2,1,3
2    1,5,4,2,3,2,8
```

What is an efficient way to load this into a 2d numpy array where ID is used as the row index and Data is split into integer values. I have looked at `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` but cannot figure out how to efficiently handle the two level data format - tabs then commas.

As asked for, my current solution is:

```
import numpy as np
import csv

size = (3, 7)
arr = np.zeros(size)

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader)

    for id, data in reader:
        arr[int(id) - 1] = [int(x) for x in data.split(',')]

print arr
```

Comment: "efficient" is not black or white, it's a gray scale. Show us your current solution so we know what is your baseline...

Comment: `pandas` has a faster `csv` reader. The numpy ones operate about the same as your code.